# cordova app ajax call to xamarin webservice

Tags: cordova, xamarin

Let me try to explain what I want to achieve. I have some web api written in c#. My web app is using the apis using ajax calls from angularjs. Now I am trying to write offline app using cordova/ionic. I dont want to rewrite the c# apis in javascript again. I just want the ajax calls (or may be doing some changes in that data fetch layer) to be sent to a android service that might be written in xamarin so that the same logic can serve the data to the app. Notice, my whole app is ideally offline. I want the smaller set of server data to be imported in sqlite db in mobile and serve the data to the app from xamarin apis. Not sure whether there is any other technology available for this. I just know about cordova and xamarin. That's why mentioned these.

The whole objective is trying to replicate the web application in mobile app in offline mode.

Not sure whether it makes sense or not. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good cordova plugins for offline feature implementation.

I prefer to use `https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage`

Almost sqlite function on cordova plugin is same with general sqlite function.

so it will be easy to use this.